# How to launch a process as a different user?

Tags: java, android, process

I want to launch a native process, from Java code, using RuntimeInstance.exec.
But the problem is, the new native process gets launched under user "me".

I want the new process to run as user "shell".

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what native process you are trying to invoke here but Android assigns unique user id for applications based on package name. You can make two apps share the same user id by specifying it in the manifest. Check this link out 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: Let's say I want to run the "ls" command through Java code. When I start the process, it runs under the user "me". Let's say I want to run this as user "shell".   Is it possible?